# PHP-GD: Compile 7 png images on top of each other into one image?

Tags: php, html, php-gd

I have a built basically a character editor on my site, it takes various images and puts them on top of each other to form an avatar.
This is HTML code:

```
<div id="AvatarImgFrame">
<img src="http://example.com/public/images/char_elements/base_dark.png"/>
<img src="http://example.com/public/images/char_elements/eyes/blue.png"/>
<img src="http://example.com/public/images/char_elements/eyes/blinking.gif"/>
<img src="http://example.com/public/images/char_elements/hair/brown.png"/>
<img src="http://example.com/public/images/char_elements/mouth/happy.png"/>
<img src="http://example.com/public/images/char_elements/pants/patrick.png"/>
<img src="http://example.com/public/images/char_elements/shoes/black.png"/>
<img src="http://example.com/public/images/char_elements/torso/shirt.png"/>
</div>
```

How could I compile basically this div into one .gif / png using PHP-GD?

Comment: Something like this - http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to merge two images: you can use `imagecopy` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)

```
$base = imagecreatefrompng('base.png');
$eyes = imagecreatefromgif('eyes.gif');

imagecopy($base, $eyes, $base_x, $base_y, $eyes_x, $eyes_y, $width, $height); 

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($base);
imagedestroy($eyes);
imagedestroy($base);
```